# Grouping sample in dashboard report jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I use transaction controller to group samples request. But the report (run command line) is generated like this
[image]

Is there any way to generate dashboard report jmeter, that include transaction controller and child sample requests like this [image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the `Generate Parent Sample` check box in your `Transaction Controller`.

So it will show both the `Transaction Controller` and child samplers. (But it can not show in the tree structure as you see in the `View Results Tree`)

Answer (score -1):

I found a small workaround for this problem.
Beside your testing, Thread Group create one more "DUMMY" with one user one loop.
Also can be used "Once Only Controller".

I put there e.g. call of index page. Or anything fast. 
To hide this one call, named the request as one of your **Transaction Controllers** Than you can have checked box as **Generate Parent Sample** and report generation will have no problem.

Hopes this helps.